# R: How to count frequency of combinations between two string columns (using dplyr, tidyr, or base r)

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr

I have a large data frame of station-to-station bike trips and it is my goal to identify the most common combinations of start and end stations. My df looks like this:

```
df <- data.frame(start_station = c('Apple', 'Bungalow', 'Carrot', 'Apple', 'Apple', 'Bungalow'),
                 end_station = c('Bungalow', 'Apple', 'Carrot', 'Bungalow', 'Bungalow', 'Apple'),
                 start_lat = c(12.3456, 23.4567, 34.5678, 12.3456, 12.3456, 23.4567),
                 start_lng = c(09.8765, 98.7654, 87.6543, 09.8765, 09.8765, 98.7654)
)
```

Ideally, I want an output that creates a ranked list of station combinations in descending order of frequency and a new column, 'ride_count' that reflects the number of exact combinations.

In the above example, I want the output to be a new dataframe I can further manipulate/visualize

```
start_station   end_station   ride_count start_lat   start_lng
Apple            Bungalow      3          12.3456    09.8765
Bungalow         Apple         2          23.4567    98.7654
Carrot           Carrot        1          34.5678    87.6543
```

Per a previous recommendation, the 'count()' command does perform the correct calculation, however I lose the other data associated with each station, like start_lat and start_lng.

Is there a way to preserve these columns?

A sincere thanks to anyone for their assistance. I've been plowing through this project efficiently, but I'm really struggling with this final geographic element.

Comment: If you have other columns that need to be retained, then please update your example to include how you expect them to be retained unchanged while these two columns are summarized/aggregated/reduced.

Comment: @r2evans I think your answer is correct?

Comment: @TarJae, waiting for the OP to expand on their mention of other fields that must not be dropped.

Comment: Apologies for failing to include that information previously. I've updated the OP.

Answer (score 1):

If we assume that other non-grouping fields are always invariant within the group, then we can do this:

```r
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  group_by(start_station, end_station) %>%
  summarize(n = n(), across(everything(), first), .groups = "drop")
# # A tibble: 3 x 5
#   start_station end_station     n start_lat start_lng
#   <chr>         <chr>       <int>     <dbl>     <dbl>
# 1 Apple         Bungalow        3      12.3      9.88
# 2 Bungalow      Apple           2      23.5     98.8 
# 3 Carrot        Carrot          1      34.6     87.7
```

If anything is variable, however, then you need to consider how to aggregate each column individually.

Comment: I genuinely can't thank you enough. I'm teaching myself R and I've burned about four hours playing around with various solutions and approaches.

You basically just blew all the wind back into my sails for the day. Shine on, you crazy diamond!

Answer (score 0):

```r
df <- data.frame(start_station = c('Apple', 'Bungalow', 'Carrot', 'Apple', 'Apple', 'Bungalow'),
                 end_station = c('Bungalow', 'Apple', 'Carrot', 'Bungalow', 'Bungalow', 'Apple'))
df_counts <- tapply(df$start_station, 
                    paste(df$start_station, df$end_station),
                    length) |> 
  as.data.frame() |>
  `colnames<-`(c('count'))
idx <- order(df_counts$count, decreasing = TRUE)
df_counts <- df_counts[ idx, , drop = FALSE]
print(df_counts)
```

```
               count
Apple Bungalow     3
Bungalow Apple     2
Carrot Carrot      1
```

Answer (score 0):

Edited dplyr approach. This adds a count for each combination of stations, and removes duplicate rows. This may not work to 'summarize' things as you demonstrated depending on the contents of other columns (lat and lng being consistent for a station allows this to work in the example).

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- data.frame(start_station = c('Apple', 'Bungalow', 'Carrot', 'Apple', 'Apple', 'Bungalow'),
                 end_station = c('Bungalow', 'Apple', 'Carrot', 'Bungalow', 'Bungalow', 'Apple'),
                 start_lat = c(12.3456, 23.4567, 34.5678, 12.3456, 12.3456, 23.4567),
                 start_lng = c(09.8765, 98.7654, 87.6543, 09.8765, 09.8765, 98.7654)
)

df %>%
  add_count(start_station, end_station, name = 'ride_count') %>%
  distinct()
#>   start_station end_station start_lat start_lng ride_count
#> 1         Apple    Bungalow   12.3456    9.8765          3
#> 2      Bungalow       Apple   23.4567   98.7654          2
#> 3        Carrot      Carrot   34.5678   87.6543          1
```

Comment: Thank you for your recommendation. I have updated the OP with two additional vectors I am trying to keep intact for later visualization (gps coordinates).

My only issue with the above solution is that it presents multiple entries for every station combination. Is there a way to limit start/end stations to a single appearance?

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, I have edited my answer. This has the same major caveat as r2evans describes in his, the non-grouped fields must be invariant for this to work as you want.